# transparency of form controls in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

How to put transparency on certain element on windows form?

I have tried a lot of codes and still nothing.

This is what looks really logical to me but it's not working.

```
 SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
 label4.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

I have put this code in the constructor.

And this is the [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4.aspx)

Comment: What colour is the label after that last line?

Comment: Opacity doesn't Exist on WinForms. Learn a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Labels` are a bit stubborn but they can be made to have transparent background. Similar question was answered here: [Transparent control over PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387267/transparent-background-label-over-picturebox)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the form itself...

```
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

You'd think it would be inherent, but in testing adding that did the trick.  Then set the control to this...

```
Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
```

That just worked in a test project not really sure why exactly.  This will probably make most of your form transparent, but hopefully you can adjust some things.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms do not have built in transparency for controls. You can, however work around this limitation.

Here is my favorite work around: http://www.doogal.co.uk/transparent.php
It works fairly well and is a generic solution rather then a "1 time" one.

Comment: additionaly, WPF handles transparency quite well, you could at least take a look at it