# VB.NET Set picturebox as background for another picturebox

Tags: vb.net, background, drawing, picturebox

I have a background picturebox and TONS of pictureboxes on the background, but how could I make the background for the pictureboxes the same as the normal background?

Comment: what do you mean by normal background.?

Comment: normal background means the background picturebox

Comment: so you want to add a background for the `picbox1` as same as the image of `picbox2`?

Comment: It is automatic when you add the pbs to the background one.  The designer won't let you do this since a picture box is not a container control.  So you'll have to write the Controls.Add() call in your code.  Or make it simple by avoiding the background pb and setting the form's BackgroundImage property.

Comment: no, I want that the background of picbox1..2..15 to be the continuing of the background picturebox. @Hans Passant could you write me some code so I can figure it out, please?

Comment: Same as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387562/17034)