# transparent picturebox on progressbar

Tags: c#, progress-bar, transparent, picturebox

I want to ask you why my picturebox in C# isn't transparent.

I created a png file with Photoshop (transparent background)
but if I place the picturebox over a PROGRESSBAR the picturebox overrides the progressbar
and i cannot see the loading of the progressbar.
(the "transparent" background from the picturebox is colored Control (like WindowsForm).

How can I implement a picture to a progressbar?

greetings

Comment: Is WPF an option for you? the overall feature support (transparency, animations, 3d, styling and templating) is much greater than winforms.

Comment: i don't know about WPF. I did lots of code in this project.
Is there not another posibillity ?

Comment: I don't know. winforms is a really old technology. You will encounter lots of these incapabilities. You should be using current technology instead.

Comment: Not sure I've got the proper mental image of a picturebox on top of a progress bar.  But the usual problem is a layering problem, the PB is owned by the form so you'll see the form as the background.  Same issue as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387562/17034)

Comment: oh. ok...  i will read something about WPF.. thanks for your help ! :)