# How to draw shapes (more than one) using List, with mouseeventargs?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, mouseevent, paint

```
class Cycle : Form1
{
    public void Draw(Graphics G,Brush b, float x, float y, float w, float h)
    {
        G.FillEllipse( b, x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

This is my Cycle class that inherits from Form1.

```
    List<Point> star = new List<Point>();
    List<Point> endd = new List<Point>();
    private void Panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        moving = true;
        Start = e.Location;
        star.Add(e.Location);
    }

    private void Panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (moving)
        {
            End = e.Location;
            Panel1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void Panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        endd.Add(e.Location);
        moving = false;
    }
```

These are my mouse event args that keeps locations.

```
    private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

            Cycle c = new Cycle();
            if (End.Y > Start.Y && End.X > Start.X)
            {
                foreach (Point pt in star)
                {
                    foreach(Point p in endd)
                        c.Draw(e.Graphics, brush, pt.X - (p.X - pt.X) / 2 - (p.Y - pt.Y) / 2, pt.Y - (p.Y - pt.Y) / 2 - (p.X - pt.X) / 2, ((p.X - pt.X) + (p.Y - pt.Y)), ((p.X - pt.X) + (p.Y - pt.Y)));
                }
            }
    }
```

And this code draws ellipses in panel. However the first ellipse has been drawn perfect but other ellipses got so big that covered all the panel.

I want to keep locations because after drawing 3-4 ellipses I will try to save the points into .txt. After that I will load it to draw again. But there is this  problem in drawing :/

Comment: Your calculation of e.g. height or top really should not involve any X values, right? Same for width and left..

Comment: No, there is no problem with that. Because when I write this code below in Panel1Paint, it works and I can draw an ellipse.                                                            Cycle c = new Cycle();
                if (End.Y > Start.Y && End.X > Start.X)
                { 
                    c.Draw(e.Graphics, brush, Start.X - (End.X - Start.X) / 2 - (End.Y - Start.Y) / 2, Start.Y - (End.Y - Start.Y) / 2 - (End.X - Start.X) / 2, ((End.X - Start.X) + (End.Y - Start.Y)), ((End.X - Start.X) + (End.Y - Start.Y)));
                }

Comment: But that way I can only draw one shape

Comment: No. You loop over your lists and calculate x and width from the xes only. Likewise for the y and height from the ys only. Combining them simply makes no sense. Btw: I always store the shapes' bounding rectangle in a ListyRectangle>. But that is another matter.

Comment: Also: I see you keep Start and End and Invalidate in the Move but the currently drawn shape is not drawn anywher, right?

Comment: Cycle c = new Cycle(); ------------------------------------------------------------if (End.Y > Start.Y && End.X > Start.X) ----------------------------------------{ ----------------------------------------------------------c.Draw(e.Graphics,brush, Start.X - (End.X - Start.X) / 2 - (End.Y - Start.Y) / 2, Start.Y - (End.Y - Start.Y) / 2 - (End.X - Start.X) / 2, ((End.X - Start.X) + (End.Y - Start.Y)), ((End.X - Start.X) + (End.Y - Start.Y))); } --------------------------------------------------------------------------Actually with this code in panel1paint, I can draw the ellipse perfectly.

Comment: those x and y problem you're talking about, I want ellipse to be equilateral. That's why I do it that way. And it works.

Comment: But I need help about using list

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767406/drawing-rectangle-in-a-panel-using-mouse/33768418#33768418) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659729/how-to-draw-shapes-and-color-them-with-a-button/41660406?s=4|26.1882#41660406) a more complex one.

Comment: I checked the example. You said him to use List<yourDrawActionClass>. What do you mean by yourDrawActionClass ? I didn't get there.

Comment: Many folks want to go beyond drawing one rype of shape with one type of pen or brush. In such a class of your own you can encapsulate all sorts of things to draw all sorts of things. [A few posts where I discuss it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+DrawAction)