# C# take a screenshot of a specific area of the form/save multiple layered picturebox as one picture

Tags: c#, image, screenshot, picturebox

My main thing is that i made a program that puts multiple pictureboxes and text labels on each other, like in Photoshop. It's working, but I want to save it into one .png or some other picture.

Comment: you can use DrawToBitmap but should note that overlapping (not nested) controls will have their z-order reversed.. - For making a photoshop-like level system have a look at [this post!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994270/photoshop-like-background-on-transparent-image/27998563?s=1|2.9432#27998563)

Comment: thank you, I think it will be my solution!