# Image layers sandwiched together

Tags: c#, image, winforms, layer

What's the best way to draw multiple image layers on-top of each other?  Also, possibly have the ability to draw a grid on-top and manually draw a selection box with the mouse, like gets drawn on the Windows desktop when you want to select multiple icons.

Comment: Is this a console program, a web app, WPF, winforms, UWP, what?

Comment: Sorry ... Good O'l Windows Form

Comment: You may want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994270/photoshop-like-background-on-transparent-image/27998563?s=1|47.8752#27998563)

Comment: I wrote [a font editor for old indexed game fonts](http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/project_stuff/2016/WWFontEditor/) a while ago (WTFPL, so go nuts). Might be worth checking it out. It's mostly nested PictureBox controls (well, subclassed to use NearestNeighbor scaling). Didn't go as far as selections though, but there's stuff like [an editing grid and hovering pixel preview](http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/project_stuff/2016/WWFontEditor/devpics/fonteditor_03_mousetrackpixel.png).

Comment: One important thing to remember is that transparency though multiple layered picture boxes doesn't work unless you specifically link them to be nested. The designer supports that for stuff like putting controls on a `Panel`, but for picture boxes I needed a bunch of code of the type `this.pxbEditGridFront.Parent = this.pxbImage` to nest them manually.

Comment: I couldn't get it to open properly.  I admit, I didn't even look into the error.  It just doesn't load the editor stuff.  INI stuff, I believe yes.  I manually opened a few .cs files.  Lot of really good code in there.  I see, lots of ways to condense the code.  If it was a real project, just meaning an open thing being worked on etc ..., I'd maybe try to get it opening fully and work on it with you.  Trying to determine if treating everything as a control is best.  PROBABLY will do first version this way.  Thinking maybe doing like that will workout good.  Thanks man, you're awesome.