# transparent button on picture box in c#

Tags: c#, button, picturebox, transparent

I would like to put many transparent button on picture box.
I am able to do this programically but all button are with solid background color.
Is it possible to make button components with transparent background and display them over picture box?
I want to do this using button because I have to have events belong to buttons.

I saw this post [Transparent control over PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387267/transparent-control-over-picturebox) but I cannot make it work with buttons.

Comment: use Parent property

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

button over picturebox doesn't support the border color on Color.Transparent, you can overcome the issue by setting an Argb color:

```
Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // transparent
```

Add below properties to a button over picturebox to do this

```
btn.TabStop = false;
btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
btn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
btn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution for this.

```
btn.FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
btn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent
btn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent
btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```