# Label disappears when an Image is assigned to a PictureBox under it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, parent-child, picturebox

I've been through quite a number of posts about adding a Label over a PictureBox, and none of the ones I've seen explain why my label disappears when over a PictureBox.
I created a completely new Label from scratch with the same problem, to rule out that perhaps I inadvertently changed some property without realizing it.

When the Form first loads, the PictureBox has no initial image set.
At this time, the Label is visible, but it's `Paint` event isn't called.

When an Imaged is assigned to the PictureBox, through a Button click, the Label is no longer visible and the Paint event still isn't called.

However, Paint events for another Label, outside of the PictureBox, are called.

In the designer I see this:

```
Me.tabDesign.Controls.Add(Me.lblTitleTest)
```

Thus, following [this post](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?647080-RESOLVED-Transparent-labelbox-above-Picturebox) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387267/transparent-control-over-picturebox), I do this:

```
Me.lblTitleTest.Location = Me.picMainImage.PointToClient(Me.tabDesign.PointToScreen(lblTitleTest.Location))
Me.lblTitleTest.Parent = Me.picMainImage
```

But it doesn't have any effect.

Next, I tried using the Paint event (below), but the event is only called for Labels **outside** of the PictureBox.
The Paint event is not called if the Label is positioned over top of the PictureBox:

```
Private Sub DrawTestTitleText(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles lblTitleTest.Paint
    MsgBox("Drawing new test title")
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Test Title", lblTitleTest.Font, New Point(10, 10), Color.Black)
End Sub
```

If I use this same code with a different Label, not over the PictureBox, the draw event fires as expected.

As a test, I tried to assign an Image from the Project's Resources to the PictureBox. That didn't help: the Label wasn't ever visible at all and its Paint event never triggered.

There must be some subtle nuance here there I'm missing.

I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Remove that `Me.lblTitleTest.Location...` line.

Comment: @LarsTech I made that change (only) and it didn't change anything.  The label is still not to be seen, and the paint event never fires.

Comment: Make sure the label location is on the screen.  Try `lblTitleTest.Location = Point.Empty`

Comment: To check that it is an included control, try to reference it in code to see if it exists, its location, etc. You should also check its Z order rendering to make sure that it's not behind something.

Comment: Partial success.  I changed the order of those 2 lines of code, setting .Parent first, then .Location, and, when it first loads with a preset image in the picturebox taken from the project's Resources, it actually works correctly.  As soon as I change the picturebox's ImageLocation through code, the label's paint event no longer fires.  Following @LarsTech's advice, I tried setting .Location to Point.Empty and it works (albeit in the top left corner), so it seems that the issue is around the .Location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relocate a Control to a different Parent container maintaining the relative position:

Assume, as in the graphic sample, that the `PictureBox.Location` is `(10, 100)`. In the Form Designer, a Label is positioned over the PictureBox, its Location is `(20, 110)`.
Its position, relative to the `PictureBox.ClientRectangle`, is then `(10, 10) => (20-10, 110-100)`).

Of course, as shown, the Label's background color is *inherited* from its Parent, the Form (transparency of Controls is *virtual*, the Parent's background is used as the background of child Control that have a transparent BackColor).

▶ The PictureBox control is not a [ContainerControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol) or a [ScrollableControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol) (it doesn't implement [IContainerControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.icontainercontrol); i.e., doesn't have the [`WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) style set), so it doesn't host a Control when you place one over its surface at design-time.

At run-time, you can set a Control's `Parent` property to a PictureBox reference, to create a new Parent-Child relation between these two Controls.
When you do, some properties related to a Control's layout need to be considered; in this case the `Location` property.
Setting the Parent doesn't change the child Control's `Location` value, which is now relative to the new Parent.

▶ The `Label.Location` is still `(20, 110)`, but now this position is related to the `PictureBox.ClientRectangle`, not the Form's. As a consequence, you have to relocate it, if you want it to keep its relative position.

1. You can subtract the new Parent's Location from the child Control's `Location`:

   ```
   [Label].Parent = [PictureBox]
   [Label].Location = Point.Subtract([Label].Location, New Size([PictureBox].Left, [PictureBox].Top))
   ```
2. Or transform the Labels's client coordinates in Screen coordinates, then apply the Screen coordinates to the Parent's client coordinates:

   ```
   [Label].Location = [PictureBox].PointToClient([Label].PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
   ```

When the Label is set to a new Parent container, its background is also *adapted* to the new Parent's background, to preserve the apparent transparency.

In `Form.Load` (assume the Label is named `label1` and the PictureBox `pictureBox1`):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    label1.Parent = pictureBox1
    label1.Location = pictureBox1.PointToClient(label1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
    ' Or
    ' label1.Location = Point.Subtract(label1.Location, New Size(pictureBox1.Left, pictureBox1.Top))
End Sub
```

```
                Design-Time:                               Run-Time:
```

[image] [image]

You can do the exact same thing drawing the text directly on the PictureBox surface, in the same position, defining the drawing Rectangle where the Text will be drawn, the same position and size as the Label you previously used.

**NOTE:**
Here, I'm using the the PictureBox `Font` property as the `Font` parameter of [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext). The PictureBox hides this property, but it's still available (belongs to the `Control` class); it's inherited from its Parent, Form or other container. You can of course specify any other Font.

See the `TextRenderer`'s [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags), to place the Text in other positions (e.g., Top/Left).
Here, `TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter` are used to center the text in the middle of the drawing box, defined by `drawingRect` in the Paint event.

```
private canvasFlags as TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or
                       TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.NoPadding
private canvasText as String = "Some Text just for show"

private sub picCanvas_Paint(sender As object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pictureBox1.Paint
   Dim pBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
   Dim drawingRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, pBox.Width - 20, pBox.Font.Height + 4)
   TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, canvasText, pBox.Font, drawingRect, Color.White, Color.Empty, canvasFlags)
End Sub
```

At Run-Time, [Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) the PictureBox when you want to repaint it to, e.g.,  replace the Text.
Resulting in:

[image: TextRenderer drawing Text]